# Image shrinking issue with CSS

Tags: css, html, image

I have a div in my html5 page that is a container for "projects". Each project then has an image and a number inside of that. When the project is selected, I'm adding a thicker border to the img I have loaded. However, adding that border shrinks the inside space allowed for the image so it appears to flash/jump/shrink when selected. Is there a technique or a way to do this so the image stays the same size but I can give the user an indication it has been selected? Right now, I'm changing the border-width and the border-color upon selection.

```css
.projects_container{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.project {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
}

.project img{
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width: 0.5px;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius:50px;
  -moz-border-radius:50px;
}

.project.toggle img{
  border-width: 3.0px;
  border-color: #ce7019;
}
```

```html
<div class="project" id='project_button_1' ><a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick='showProject("1")'><img src='urlhere'></img><p>1</p></a></div>
```

Comment: Looks like your sample code is missing something. Console gives "error {"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: showProject is not defined"...}`

Answer (score 2):

To avoid that "jump" you can include the value of the `border` inside the fixed dimensions of your `img` with the property `box-sizing:border-box` but that will decrease the size of your img.

I will suggest another way to highlight your img with the `box-shadow` property:

<sub>Note: In order to see an example I've changed your code to work on hover</sub>

```css
.project {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
}
.project img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition:all 1s;
}
.project:hover img{
  border-color:red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="project">
  <img src='http://placekitten.com/120'></img>
</div>
```